Wordpress articles aren't showing up on custom theme
I've done a html website like a half year ago and now migrate it into wordpress with just pasting the html files into php files which are set as template.
If I'm now creating an article in wordpress, which was the only reason to migrate to cms, I'm not able to view it at the homepage under the fitting url.
The url looks like this: domain.com/?p=78 and I'm only forwarded to the startpage without seeing any trace of the article.
Do you have an idea what's the issue. Do I need to implement a extra function in the index.php for viewing articles? Can I forward it to another page where I use a function to view these articles?
I've created multiple times new articles and watched what happened. It always forward to the startpage set on domain.com with an "/?p=number" added. I have no clue what's the problem is and hope for your help.

Sorry for the challenge, I have been working on a similar situation. Am sure you want to display a single post.
So for that to work please add a file called single.php in the same folder with index.php.
And then follow the instructions found here:WordPress Posts Templates on Single.php section

I agree with @Clever Gambe it looks like you have copied the index.php file with single.php due to which it showing like this, can you please share the URL of the website so I can take more closer look into this.
